# How to find the midpoint given the linear equation

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given the linear equation: $$y = 7247.5188  -2395.0376x$$ how do I find the midpoint of this line?

Comment: How are you defining midpoint in this case? Perhaps it is the midpoint of the line segment that is in the first quadrant?

Comment: yes, it is this midpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have line $\ell\equiv y=a-bx$ with $a,b>0$ then the midpoint of the segment in the first quadrant can be found as follows:

1. the absis of the midpoint is $\frac b{2a}$ (the average between $0$ and the intersection $\ell$ with $X$-axe.
2. the ordinat of the midpoint is $\frac a2$ (the average between $0$ and the intersection $\ell$ with $Y$-axe.